# Is there a de facto standard way to access PHP files under current directory

Tags: php

What is the way most developers access files under the script's current location?

Is one more efficient than the other?

```
$stuff=file_get_contents('../somedirectory/somefile.json');   //This doesn't work.  Just curious why?
$stuff=file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__).'/somedirectory/somefile.json');
$stuff=file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../somedirectory/somefile.json');
$stuff=file_get_contents('/var/www/mysite/somedirectory/somefile.json');

require_once('../somedirectory/somefile.php');   //This doesn't work.  Just curious why?
require_once(dirname(__DIR__).'/somedirectory/somefile.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../somedirectory/somefile.php');
require_once('/var/www/mysite/somedirectory/somefile.php');
```

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @Dagon  Maybe, but perhaps there is a way to do so which is more efficient than others?

Comment: @user1032531 the way you specify paths in your sources is not the thing you ever need to optimise. The rule of thumb for performance optimisation: measure, then after you've proven something is slow - optimise what is slow.

Comment: @zerkms  I totally agree.  I just wish to be consistent on what I do, and would like to fault on something that is 0.00001% better.

Comment: better is just an opinion here

Comment: @Dagon Acknowledge.  I revised the post.

Comment: i usually use `../../../` as i know my structure and it wont be moving it. I would use `__DIR__` etc for code i was expecting others to use and may not know where they would put it

Comment: Thanks Dagon.  I take it then `dirname()` is not a preferred solution?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) = __DIR__` same result so `__DIR__` seems cleaner to me

Comment: did not notice  `dirname(__DIR__)` above that makes little sense, i would expect to see `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: No, I mean `dirname(__DIR__ ).'/bla'` or  `__DIR__ .'/../bla'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly a matter of opinion, but what you see the most in open source PHP is only using the `__DIR__` constant plus a relative path, e.g.:

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/../foo.php';
```

Using just `../` is always relative to the current working dir, so that is typically (i.e. for most cases) unusable:

```
 require_once getcwd() . '/foo.php';
 // is equivalent to:
 require_once './foo.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reason why `../` shouldn't be used.

Comment: makes sense in a project that does not know where it may be loaded, may not make sens for your personal usage

Comment: So, your experience is most will use a relative path to `__DIR__`, and not `dirname()` to go lower?

Comment: @user1032531 honestly unless you need to "get a path relative to current working dir" specifically - there is no (?) other real reason to not use absolute path with `__DIR__`

Comment: @zerkms.  I am good with relative paths and using `__DIR__`, but should one use `dirname(__DIR__ ).'/bla'` or `__DIR__ .'/../bla'`

Comment: @user1032531 which one you like better? It's a matter of preference. I find the latter much more acceptable, but it's irrational.

Comment: @zerkms  The one you like better if you do so for a reason.  I read a previous stackoverflow post stating that `dirname()` is costly, but I don't know if that is true.

Comment: @user1032531 that's why I explicitly stated that it's irrational: I just *like* it better, there is no strong *technical* motivation behind it. "dirname() is costly" --- it does not matter, check my comment about performance optimisations once again.

Comment: @zerkms  I'll go with the later and be consistent as consistency is likely better than right for this scenario.

Comment: @user1032531 "as consistency is likely better" --- and that's a really good idea :-)

Comment: I would not advise using `dirname` because it gets pretty much unreadable if you need to go a few paths up. Anecdote time: before the `__DIR__` constant was introduced, you'd use `dirname(__FILE__)`. In some piece of code I once wrote I left a little joke behind, introducing a function called `malkovich`. I needed to go up about 12 steps or so, so the code that resolved the path now read: `malkovich(malkovich(malkovich(malkovich...etc)))`. Proven by example that it really gets weird nesting the function that much. (but still, very opinionated)

Comment: @GerardvanHelden  On this case, maybe not so opinionated as you all agree!  Thank you for your help and a description of your previous experiences.  Right or wrong (right I think), I will not use `dirname()` unless conditions require.  PS.  Only people on this site could appreciate your little joke!